# How to modify a recurrent PayPal payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I’m trying to implement the following scenario:

1. User approves a recurrent weekly payment (subscription) for a selected package size
2. Every week the user can:
   a. Cancel a specific week delivery and avoid paying for this week
   b. Modify the package size and pay less/more for this time only
   c. Add additional items and get charged for them in addition to theweekly package

Looking at the documentation I did not find the APIs that allowing me to modify the subscription according to my needs.

Can someone please direct me to the right documentation or provide a code snippet?

Thanks,
Yossi

Answer (score 1):

I think this is unsupported. You may wish to look into subscription management services like [Spreedly](http://spreedly.com/) and Zuora.com for these use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. I'm trying to implement a similar thing. What I've tried is to issue a subscription modification with a free trial period. But it seems that the trial period parameters (a1,t1,p1) are ignored on a subscription modification. I've found some (unofficial) references that free periods cannot be inserted into an existing subscription, which is exactly what we need.

I'm pretty bummed this isn't supported. I cannot think of a clean way around it.